# How to have variable definition in place of command?

Tags: bash

I am using chroot in a script, the purpose is to run a command, here is chroot syntax:

```
chroot [OPTION] NEWROOT [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

The problem is the command I am running needs to take a variable defition, like this -

```
chroot   /myroot   FOO=BAR  my_cmd
```

But when I do this, I get error message `bash : FOO=BAR, no such file or directory`, looks like the first position must be command.

Is there a workaround of this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$ sudo FOO=bar chroot /srv/Chroot/precise-i386/ env | grep FOO
FOO=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use alias here . 
for example

alias foo= 'your command  '

place this command in your bashrc with

gedit .bashrc

then do source .bashrc

do all these in your terminal .

some one edit my post to put it in format because I'm doing this from my mobile .